# Import-AzureRmRedisCache : Long running operation failed with status 'Conflict'

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-redis-cache

I'm getting a strange error with PowerShell AzureRM 4.4.0.  When I run  `Import-AzureRmRedisCache -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $rediscache -Files $sasKeyForBlob -Force` It runs for about 1 minute and the throws up the below error.  The files are only 35KiB!  I've searched the web and I can't find any reference to Long running operation failed with status 'Conflict'.

The Error:
Import-AzureRmRedisCache : Long running operation failed with status 'Conflict'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-AzureRmRedisCache -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $rediscache -F ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Import-AzureRmRedisCache], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RedisCache.ImportAzureRedisCache

Comment: What is your Redis Cache sku? Import/Export is in preview and is only available for premium tier caches.

Comment: Can you send us your cache name, timestamp of when you got this error and email us at azurecache@microsoft.com? Thanks.